# How to compute the RMS(root-mean-squared) distance between 2D points and the origin?

Tags: matrix-norms, computer-vision

In Hartley and Zisserman's book Multiple View Geometry in computer vision, when it comes to data normalization, it states

> Namely the points should be translated so that their centroid is at the origin, and scaled so that their RMS (root-mean-squared) distance from the origin is $\sqrt{2}$.

Assume I have a matrix in which the 2D image points are stored column by column, e.g.

\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6
\end{matrix}

where the first row stores the $x$ coordinates and the second row stores the $y$ coordinates. So the centroid may be computed with

`Eigen::Vector2d centroid = observations.rowwise().mean();`

Now if I have **1D** $n$ numbers of a discrete distribution, the RMS **error** can simply be computed with the squara root of the mean sqaured deviation.

But I don't know HOW to compute the RMS **distance** between the **2D points** and the origin, methematically and programmingly.

Can someone shed some info to me?

Comment: Can't we just take the norm of each of the ordered pairs of points?

Comment: @K.defaoite So just $\sqrt{\sum{(x_i - origin)^2}/ n}$    ?

Comment: Yes, for a set of points $\{\mathbf{r}_1,...,\mathbf{r}_n\}$ the RMSE of their norms (i.e, distances from the origin) should do. This is indeed given by $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\Vert\mathbf{r}_i-(0,0)\Vert^2}{n}}$$